# Data Retrieval Limits and Update Frequency for Amazon Selling Partner API Reports

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm reaching out to the community to inquire about the data retrieval limitations and update frequency for several Amazon Selling Partner API reports that I cannot find in the documentation. I'm particularly interested in the following reports:

- GET_FBA_REIMBURSEMENTS_DATA
- GET_FBA_FULFILLMENT_CUSTOMER_RETURNS_DATA
- GET_FBA_FULFILLMENT_CUSTOMER_SHIPMENT_REPLACEMENT_DATA
- GET_V2_SETTLEMENT_REPORT_DATA_FLAT_FILE_V2
- GET_LEDGER_DETAIL_VIEW_DATA
- GET_FBA_MYI_ALL_INVENTORY_DATA
- GET_FBA_ESTIMATED_FBA_FEES_TXT_DATA

I'd appreciate any insights on the following:

1. **Maximum Data Returned per Call**: Is there a maximum number of days of
   data that can be retrieved in a single API call for each of these
   reports?
2. **Historical Data Availability**: How far back in time can I access data
   using these reports (e.g., 30 days, 90 days, or longer)?
3. **Data Update Frequency**: How often is the data in these reports
   updated by Amazon (e.g., daily, hourly, etc.)?

Any information or personal experiences shared would be greatly helpful.
Thanks in advance for your assistance!